# How to implement interface concept in selenium webdriver testng

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to the java selenium testng. As i am using multiple browser testing in automation selenium webdriver testng, how shall i use interface concept for multiple browsers. I am trying to make the selenium webdriver framework completly object oriented.
Below is my piece of code

```
public class BrowserFactory{

    public WebDriver driver;

    @Parameter("browser")
    @BeforeTest
    public void launchBrowser(String browser) throws Exception{

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Path+"/geckodriver");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("safari"))
        {
            driver = new SafariDriver();
        }
        driver.get("");
    }
```

How shall i implement interface here? also i have not added get("Pass the link to open").

Please help.

Comment: What interface do you aim to implement? Are you trying to add new `WebDriver`?

Comment: Yes Prokhorov. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Ok. If you want to implement your own web driver, then this is a huge programming undertaking that is outside of scope of StackOverflow. In general, you will want to look at what methods `WebDriver` interface has and implement each method in such way that it doesn't violate the contract (most drivers communicate with real browsers via JNA or something similar to achieve that goal). You will also want to study public API of your browser of choice to see where you can cut corners.

Answer (score 1):

### Interface:

In Java an interface is a type of reference. It is almost similar to a class. It is a collection of abstract methods. A class implements an interface and inherits the abstract methods of the interface. An interface may contain constants, default methods and static methods. Method bodies exist only for the default methods and static methods. You can find the detailed discussion [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm).

---

### WebDriver:

WebDriver provides a platform to remotely instruct the functioning of web browsers. WebDriver provides us a set of interfaces to discover and manipulate elements those are currently attached to the `HTML DOM`. You can find the detailed discussion [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/).

---

### Usage:

If you put your own code block in an IDE (I am using Eclipse Neon v2) and mouse hover the word `WebDriver`, you will observe that Java Compiler hints you about `Interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver` as follows:

[image]

The **`I`** in violet indicates that `WebDriver` is an interface. So through `public WebDriver driver;` we are declaring an instance of the interface `WebDriver`.